# How to make my matrix array become like this?

Tags: arrays, user-interface, function, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like this:

```
A = 1 2 3

      4 5 6

      7 8 9
```

My question is how I want to make my matrix to be like this:

```
A11 = 1

A12 = 2

A13 = 3

A21 = 4

A22 = 5

A23 = 6

A31 = 7

A32 = 8

A33 = 9
```

Because i have to multiply A21 with A22 which is 4x5=20.

Comment: Is it really necessary to create all those variables? If you want to multiply A21 with A22 you can just write A(2,1)*A(2,2). Or is there another reason you need to do this? EDIT: Looking at ypnos answer I understood your question, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear to me.

To create the matrix, use ',' (or nothing) to delimit columns, ';' to delimit rows.

```
A = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9];
```

To access the matrix, you can use a 1-dimensional index as well as a 2-dimensional index.
E.g. A21 is `A(2, 1)` as well as `A(0*3+2)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually need variables such as 'A11', 'A12' etc. you could do as follows:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];

for i = 1:size(A,1)
    for j = 1:size(A,2)             
        eval(sprintf('A%d%d = %f;',i,j,A(i,j)));            
    end 
end


A21 * A22 
# will result in 20
```

Maybe not the best way, but it will create the variables for you.